# Inconsistent "Cannot find name 'x'" Typescript errors in VS Code

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, visual-studio-code

My app compiles (transpiles) just fine, but Visual Studio Code is still showing a lot of errors:

[image]

In some of these cases (e.g. `angular` and `ionic`), the problem is a global variable/namespace that is added via our inclusion of Angular/Ionic is not recognized.  Most of the errors are of the form "Cannot find name 'angular/ionic/ng" (etc).

To make things even stranger, I've noticed that the file that is initially open when I load VS Code doesn't have any errors at all.  The red underlined errors are in the *other* files in other tabs/editors.

What's going on?  How do I get VS Code to consistently acknowledge that these globals/namespaces do, in fact, exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After many sad days of chasing this problem - I finally found a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7018#issuecomment-225505892) on the VS Code GitHub that explains what is going on.

## tl;dr

My `tsconfig.json` file was configured incorrectly.  To fix it, I removed the `files` section.  You may need to remove it in your project, as well, or perhaps just "fix" it to include all relevant `.ts` files.

## Longer version

> Adding a files [section] limits our project to those two files and **if you open other files not referenced by those two files then they end up in an isolated virtual project**. You either need to leave out the files section (then all .ts files underneath the tsconfig.json file are automatically considered part of the project) or you need to list all files of your project in that section.

My original `tsconfig.json file was:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts",
        "src/typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

So, VS Code thought that my project only consisted of two files.  Other `.ts` files that I loaded were considered an "isolated virtual project" - not hard to understand why they were generating errors.

I changed my `tsconfig.json` file to the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

**Problem solved!**

Comment: ok, that's so awesome !!!!!!!  i had filesGlob and an empty files array.  removed the files array as you suggested, restarted vscode and voila !!!!!!  1,000,000 thank you's !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure thing! I'm glad my protracted pain could at least lessen your suffering! :)

Comment: @MikeGraham the part about restarting is important

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had no `tsconfig.json` at all!

Creating it with default values fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me I also have this exact problem if I open vscode pointing to a sub directory of the application (like 'src') rather than the root of the application. Maybe this is because the typescript.config is in the root directory, but I'm not sure if that's the reason.